# I don't see the pattern.. does anyone understand this..?

Tags: puzzle, pattern-recognition

Note.. the numbers are actually in a 7 x 6 grid.. graphics did not show here..

```
What is the number in the * cell?
88      63              
    25      9           
        16      24      
            13      49  
                *       10
                    9
```

Possible answers

```
15

52

25

17
```

Comment: If the left number is greater than the right one, then the number under them in the middle is their difference.

Comment: And otherwise it's the sum of the digits.

Answer (score 2):

the answer is more simple...just add all digits in the row to equal the number below:
8+8+6+3 = 25
2+5+9 = 16
and so on...

correct answer = 17

Comment: As a heads up, you might want to remove the part referring to xaviermo2's comment; "answer above" won't necessarily always refer to that and won't make any sense at all if the comment ever gets deleted (which it might, since its purported solution is wrong)